# Points are not drawn

Tags: opengl, opengl-2.0, opengl-1.x

First of all: yes, I know this is a really outdated programming interface. But some target machines don't even guarantee OpenGL 2.1, that's why it still has to be used.

My problem: when drawing some geometries with OpenGL, points and polylines that consist of 2 points only are not drawn. Is there a polyline with at least three coordinate points, it works smoothly. So this is not working:

```
glBegin(GL_POINT);
glVertex3f(...);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex3f(...);
glVertex3f(...);
glEnd();
```

...while this creates results as expected:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex3f(...);
glVertex3f(...);
glVertex3f(...);
...
glEnd();
```

This is my initialisation:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glHint( GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
glHint( GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );
glHint( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST );

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
```

Any idea what the reason for this behaviour is? Why are simple lines and dots not drawn?

Comment: does it stop working if you remove a vertex from a working 3-point line strip, or do completely different 1 and 2-point drawing commands not work?

Comment: dognotdog: it stops when removing one vertex to leave only two

Comment: very strange, have you tried it without smoothing, or switching the renderers (software/hardware)? It might as well be some obscure bug you're hitting, at least I am not seeing any obvious reason how this could happen, even in the strange world of OpenGL.

Comment: Found it: it needs to be GL_POINTS not GL_POINT, and the problem with the lines was just a follow-up, no lines have been drawn that were followed by this wrong glBegin(GL_POINT)

Answer (score 1):

Try `GL_POINTS` rather than `GL_POINT`. `GL_POINTS` is a sort of Enumeration that tells OpenGL to render points. I believe `GL_POINT` is used to modify the rendering mode (render solid polygons (`GL_FILL`), render wireframe polygons (`GL_LINE`), or render disconnected vertices of polygons (`GL_POINT`)). I wanted to clarify before but could not think of a good way to explain it at the time.